# forward declaration and namespaces (c++)

Tags: c++, namespaces, forward-declaration

My Problem:

Got two classes, class A and B, so i got A.h and A.cpp and B.h and B.cpp.
A needs to know B and B needs to know A. I solved it the following way (i don't know why it has to be so...)

A.h:

```
#include "B.h"
class A{ ...
```

A.cpp:

```
#include "A.h"
```

B.h:

```
#include "A.h"
class A; // forward declaration
class B { ...
```

B.cpp:

```
#include "B.h"
```

I used one forward declaration and it works.

The Problem is, that both classes need to be in the namespace "ui". Or at least I think this is the meaning:

A.h:

```
#include "B.h"
namespace ui{
  class A;
}

class A{ ...
```

B.h:

```
#include "A.h"
namespace ui{
  class B;
}

class B{ ...
```

This doesn't work anymore. What do I have to do now to make it work again with namespace and forward declaration?

Both have to be in this namespace. I'm working with Qt and the lines "namespace ui{" etc. are needed. And both classes need to know each other.
I already tried just to make this:

```
namespace ui{
 class A;
 class B;
}
```

in both headers, but this doesn't work...

Btw: All Header-Files also got the "ifndef"-mechanism.

Comment: What does "This doesn't work anymore." mean? Please post the exact compiler/linker errors.

Answer (score 13):

If I understand you right, you declare 2 different types with such a construct:

```
#include "B.h"
namespace ui{
  class A;
}

class A{ ... };
```

Here you state that there is a `class A` in the namespace `ui`, but you define a `class A` in the global namespace. Therefore `ui::A` is declared but *never* defined. Move the definition of `A` to the `ui` namespace as well:

```
#include "B.h"
namespace ui{
  class A;
}

//somewhere later:
namespace ui
{
  class A{ ... };
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
// A.h
namespace ui {
   class A; // forward
   class B {
   };
}



// B.h
namespace ui {
   class B; // forward
   class A {
   };
}



// A.cpp
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"



// B.cpp
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"
```

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there.  This should work:

```
// A.h
namespace ui {

class B;
class A {
  ...
};

} // namespace ui
```

and

```
// B.h
namespace ui {

class A;
class B {
  ...
};

} // namespace ui
```

The only thing you got wrong is that you have to define the classes inside the namespace; it's not enough to forward-declare them inside the namespace.

Comment: I cant do this. This is the auto-generated text by QT-Designer. It just does this. I dont know why. Btw also in my first example that i declared as working i also need two forward declarations.

Comment: You may have noticed that you got three answers all saying almost exactly the same thing?  This is the only way to make it work.  If QT-Designer can't be persuaded to put its class definitions inside the "`namespace ui {` ... `}`" block, then you're stuck with those classes being in the global namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Apart to forward-declare the class from within its namespace (as other answers correctly say), remember to either *use* (prepend) that namespace when referring to the forward-declared class, or add a `using` clause:

```
// B.h
namespace Y { class A; } // full declaration of
// class A elsewhere

namespace X {
    using Y::A;   // <------------- [!]
    class B {
        A* a; // Y::A
    };
}
```

---

Ref: [Namespaces and Forward Class Declarations](https://www.epstudiossoftware.com/namespaces-and-forward-class-declarations/)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very Qt-specific question.

When Qt Designer auto-generates code file for you, the `Ui` namespace is a separate namespace from your classes. There are actually two different classes being declared here: `class A` in the global namespace, and `class Ui::A` in the  `Ui` namespace. The second class holds all of the controls which Qt generates for you (when you use the form designer), and the first class (in the global namespace) has all of your logic.

The version of Qt Creator I'm using (3.1) will also generate a private member for `class A` (not `Ui::A`): `private: Ui::A* ui;`, which is setup with `ui->setUp(this)`. You can then access controls (e.g. `ui->lineEdit->toPlainText();`.